# Changing the precedence of operators defined in a monadic expressions

Tags: haskell

Since we cannot use infixl nor infixr within a monadic expression, how could we change the precedence and associativity of an operator defined within a monadic expression?

For example, how could we change the precedence of (.=) in:

```
... = do
  let (.=) = ...
  infixl 5 .=  -- this produces a 'parse error'
  ...
```

Comment: You can define the `infixl`/`infixr` at the top of the module.

Comment: But, at the beginning of the module, we do not have the operator (.=) defined, which only exists within the monadic expression

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add fixity annotations inside `let` and `where`. Whether you are inside a `do` block or not is irrelevant.

For instance, this compiles and runs fine:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let (###) :: Int -> Int -> Int
        x ### y = x
        infixl 5 ###
    print (3 ### 7 ### 9)  -- outputs 3
```